# Adding a value to a column that indicates a record is from which table + sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, rows, calculated-columns

I have three tables (DocIncome, DocOutgoing, and Financial), each of their records have a specific ID and the Date of when it occurred.

I am not an expert in this but I've wrote a query to bring all the information I need in one output,

```
   SELECT        [DepositNo],[ID], [Submitdate]
   FROM            [Doc_Income]
   WHERE        (DepositNo = 7081)

   UNION

   SELECT        [DepositNo],[ID], [TransferDate]
   FROM            [Doc_Outgoing]
   WHERE        (DepositNo = 7081)

   UNION

   SELECT            [Tansactions_Details].[DepositNo], [Transactions_Deposits].[ID], [Transactions_Deposits].[TransDate]
   FROM        [Tansactions_Details], [Transactions_Deposits]
   WHERE       [DepositNo]=7081 AND ([Tansactions_Details].[Ref_TransactionID] = [Transactions_Deposits].[ID])

   ORDER BY Submitdate
```

Let's say this is the output:

```
DepositNo|    ID    |  Date
  7081   |   7081   |  2006-10-28 00:00:00.000
  7081   |   21121  |  2006-10-28 00:00:00.000
  7081   |   21122  |  2006-11-21 00:00:00.000
  7081   |   21880  |  2008-03-16 16:41:27.000
  7081   |   23674  |  2008-10-14 11:13:58.000
```

but How can I indicate that e.g. record #1 is from the Income table? Because I will need that info in the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own column in the output by giving a literal string and naming the column like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, 'SomeText' AS MyColumn
FROM MyTable
```

This makes your query look like this:

```
SELECT        [DepositNo],[ID], [Submitdate], 'DocIncome' AS TableName
FROM            [Doc_Income]
WHERE        (DepositNo = 7081)

UNION

SELECT        [DepositNo],[ID], [TransferDate], 'DocOutgoing' AS TableName
FROM            [Doc_Outgoing]
WHERE        (DepositNo = 7081)

UNION

SELECT            [Tansactions_Details].[DepositNo], [Transactions_Deposits].[ID], [Transactions_Deposits].[TransDate], 'Doc_Income' AS TableName
FROM        [Tansactions_Details], [Financial]
WHERE       [DepositNo]=7081 AND ([Tansactions_Details].[Ref_TransactionID] = [Transactions_Deposits].[ID])

ORDER BY Submitdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with a string to identify the table name into your union query e.g.

```
SELECT        [DepositNo],[ID], [Submitdate], 'INCOME_TABLE' as TableName
   FROM            [Doc_Income]
   WHERE        (DepositNo = 7081)
```